# How to write monoid protocol in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, monoids

The following does not work, for obvious reasons.

```
(defprotocol Monoid
  (mappend [a b])
  (mzero []))
```

`mzero` has zero arguments, and zero argument methods are not allowed (or do not make sense) in protocols. In Haskell or Scala, where the dispatch is type-based rather than value-based, this is not a problem.

What would be the correct way to conceptualize and write `Monoid` protocol in Clojure?

Comment: why do you need it to be a protocol rather than a module?  if you are expecting different implementations then how would haskell infer which implementation is required in a particular use case?  (i think it's a good question, i'm just trying to chase down the issue involved).

Comment: @andrewcooke Haskell infers based on the static type at the use site. The method that is called is resolved statically.

Comment: @andrewcooke, what would module mean in the context of your statement?

Comment: @missingfaktor - what i said was wrong.  what i should have said is that `mappend` would be in the protocol, but the equivalent of `mzero` would be a function that creates an implementation of that protocol (and lives in a namespace - module - with the implementation).  what i am missing, from the above, is how something like `mzero` can be implied by context *separately* from a particular implementation.

Comment: @andrewcooke, this example might help to understand how this works in Haskell: http://ideone.com/j1nnz.

Comment: I heard new Reducers library has monoids, so I suppose there exists some way to encode this in Clojure. :-)

Comment: http://clojure.com/blog/2012/05/08/reducers-a-library-and-model-for-collection-processing.html [for reference for others] also, i am going to delete some of my questions above because it's just noise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

looking at the [source](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/89e5dce0fdfec4bc09fa956512af08d8b14004f6/src/clj/clojure/core/reducers.clj#L279), the way that this is implemented in the [new reducers library](http://clojure.com/blog/2012/05/08/reducers-a-library-and-model-for-collection-processing.html) is not as a procotol but an overloaded function.  a no-args call is mzero; two args call is mappend.

more exactly, `monoid` takes two arguments - `op` and `ctor` and returns a function which, when called with no arguments, evaluates `ctor`, and when called with two, delegates to `op`.

this is consistent with how zero is handled in a fold, for example - `reduce` (fold) will evaluate the function being folded with no args to find the zero, if necessary.

i feel a bit ashamed to show something so unexciting, but i don't see how you can do better within clojure.  thanks for the explanations/education in the comments.

Comment: Okay, that answers the question. Thank you!