# What is the Clojure equivalent of Scalaz Foldable's foldmap?

Tags: scala, clojure, scalaz, fold

In the [Scalaz trait `Foldable`](http://scalaz.googlecode.com/svn/continuous/latest/browse.sxr/scalaz/Foldable.scala.html) we see the [method `foldMap`](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Foldable.html) with the following description

> Map each element of the structure to a [[scalaz.Monoid]], and combine the results.

```
def foldMap[A,B](fa: F[A])(f: A => B)(implicit F: Monoid[B]): B
```

You can use it like this:

```
scala> List(1, 2, 3) foldMap {identity}
res1: Int = 6

scala> List(true, false, true, true) foldMap {Tags.Disjunction}
res2: scalaz.@@[Boolean,scalaz.Tags.Disjunction] = true
```

My question is: **What is the Clojure equivalent of Scalaz Foldable's foldmap?**

Comment: Related: [How to write monoid protocol in Clojure?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10767793/406435)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default Clojure has no monadic composition. For that you need libraries like [algo.monads](https://github.com/clojure/algo.monads) or [fluokitten](http://fluokitten.uncomplicate.org/).

A monoid in Haskell and Skalaz is a class that implements three functions:

- `mempty` returns the identity element
- `mappend` combines two values of the same type
- `mconcat` used to convert collections of that type to items and v.v.

Clojure has no fold function that invokes all three of those; `reduce` is the go-to higher order function for accumulating over a collection.

By default it takes 3 parameters: a reducer function, an accumulator and a collection. The reducer function is used to combine the accumulator and one item from the collection at a time. It need not accept identical types like `mappend`. The third is always a collection, which is why `mconcat` is not needed.

In the context of Clojure's 1.5 `clojure.reducers` and `clojure.core/reduce`, there *is* a monoid however: a function that returns it's identity element when called without parameters.

For instance:

```
(+) => 0 
(*) => 1
(str) => ""
(vector) => []
(list) => ()
```

This 'monoid' function is used as the reducer in the two parameter version of `reduce`; its 'monoidal identity' or `mempty` is called to create the initial accumulator.

`(reduce + [1 2 3]) => (reduce + (+) [1 2 3]) => (reduce + 0 [1 2 3])`

So if you want to translate the examples here, you need to find or make a function that has such a 'monoid' implementation to use it in the dual arity reduce.

For disjunction, Clojure has `or`:

```
(defmacro or
  "Evaluates exprs one at a time, from left to right. If a form
  returns a logical true value, or returns that value and doesn't
  evaluate any of the other expressions, otherwise it returns the
  value of the last expression. (or) returns nil."
  {:added "1.0"}
  ([] nil)
  ([x] x)
  ([x & next]
      `(let [or# ~x]
         (if or# or# (or ~@next)))))
```

It does have a 'monoid' implementation, `([] nil)`. However, `or` is implemented as a macro to support short circuiting, and can only be used within an expression to be expanded, not as a function parameter:

```
(reduce or [false true false true true])
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't take value of a macro: #'clojure.core/or, compiling
```

So we need a 'new' `or` that's a true function for disjunction. It should also implement a no-arity version returning nil:

```
(defn newor
  ([] nil)
  ([f s] (if f f s)))
```

So now we have a function with a 'monoid' implementation, and you can use it in the dual arity reduce:

```
(reduce newor [true false true true])
=> true
```

Seems a bit complicated until you understand why Clojure implemented `or` as a multiple arity macro

```
(or true false true true)
=> true
```

Comment: `or` is not implemented as a macro `to support variable arity` ; functions can have multiple arity too. `or`is implemented as a macro to support *lazy evaluation*.

Answer (score 2):

I'm willing to be proven wrong, but I don't think Clojure has monoids, as such. However, check out [this article](http://www.leonardoborges.com/writings/2012/12/05/monads-in-small-bites-part-iii-monoids/) that describes how you would create a monoid.

Specifically for your two examples, I would write:

```
(reduce + [1 2 3]) ; => 6
```

and

```
(some identity [true false true true]) ;=> true
```

Note that `identity` is *not* the Identity monoid. :-)